# VS 2012 Support for Windows mobile 6

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-mobile, windows-ce, windows-mobile-6.5

I've read [here](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/595712/no-support-for-windows-ce-and-compact-framework-development-in-vs2010) that Microsoft will add support for Windows CE in visual studio 2012, but I haven't seen this project template in VS 2012.

My question: is there going to be support for Windows CE 5 (more specifically Windows Mobile 6) or not ? and if it is going to be supported do I have to install something else?

Thank in advance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

So far Microsoft has only publicly annouced a vague "we'll support Windows CE in VS12 in the furture."  They've not elaboarated at all, but based on my knowledge of their past actions (not any secret insider info) there are my predictions.  None, all or anywhere in between may come true.

1. Support will be provided as a out-of-band install.  So it's not part of VS12, but a plug in that a different team will release.
2. Release will likely be timed with a release of Windows CE, so I'd expect it around the same time as Windows CE v. Next (which they've not given a time table for either).
3. They will likely drop support for old processors. I'd expect it to be x86 and ARM - probably v5 and later - only.
4. There will be both native and managed support.
5. Given the lack of information on the CF, I wouldn't expect great changes.  Maybe you'll get some perf improvements, etc, but do not expect C# 4.0 support.
6. I suspect there will be some backward compatibility, but how far is a really good question.  6.0R3 would be fairly safe, but 5.0?  How do you deal with the fact that 5.0 supported processors that will unlikely be supported in vNext?  I think Windows Embedded Handheld 6.5.3 would likely be supported, so maybe they'll give an "ARM-only" condition.

Again, this is all conjecture, so take it with a grain of salt.  Until they publicly announce something, including timelines, all we can do is guess.  The fact that they announced something at all indicates to me that we should expect more details in the next 30-60 days.

**EDIT**

Some more details of Studio 2012 support has been released, though they've really not made any clarifications on what older versions of the OS and Platforms might be supported.  We know that Studio 2012 will have support both native and managed development for Smart Devices in Q2 of 2013. As I said, backward-compatibility has yet to be announced so we don't know how far back we might be able to target.

Comment: I feel like I'll be adding Android to my resume, if I continue to develop for mobile devices.

Comment: I'd also suspect that Metro should be on the resume as well.  I think Windows CE will only be for embedded devices moving forward (which is what I use them for anyway) and that if you want a mobile device (tablet, phone or whatever) it's going to be based on either Phone or Windows for ARM.

Comment: I've also been doing Android work and believe me, Android is no Panacea.  It's got all the platform support nightmares that WinMo had back in about 2005, and the tools (outside of Mono) suck if you're used to Studio.